# cannot get logs from docker container using golang docker sdk

Tags: api, docker, go, sdk

I want to compile untrusted code in docker container, so I want to test exec command

```
import (
"context"
"github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
"github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
"github.com/docker/docker/client"
log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
"io"
"os"
)

func main() {
dockerClient, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.WithVersion("1.38"))
if err != nil{
    log.Error("error when create dockerClient ",err)
}

ctx := context.Background()

container, err := dockerClient.ContainerCreate(ctx,&container.Config{
    Image:"golang",
    OpenStdin:true,
    Tty:true,
    AttachStdin:true,
    Cmd:[]string{"bash"},
    AttachStdout:true,
    AttachStderr:true,


},nil,nil,"")

if err := dockerClient.ContainerStart(ctx,container.ID,types.ContainerStartOptions{});err != nil{
    log.Error("error when start container", err)
    return
}

idResponse, err :=dockerClient.ContainerExecCreate(ctx,container.ID,types.ExecConfig{
    Cmd:[]string{"echo","hello"},
    Tty:true,
    AttachStderr:true,
    AttachStdout:true,
    AttachStdin:true,
    Detach:true,
})

if err := dockerClient.ContainerExecStart(ctx,idResponse.ID,types.ExecStartCheck{

}); err != nil{
    log.Error("error when exec start ", err)
}

reader, err :=dockerClient.ContainerLogs(ctx,container.ID,types.ContainerLogsOptions{
    ShowStdout:true,
    ShowStderr:true,


})

if err != nil{
    log.Error("error when containerLogs",err)
}

go io.Copy(os.Stdout,reader)

<- make(chan struct{})
```

}

as you can see, I create an new exec process, exec a new cmd called "echo hello", I want to get output from running container and show in my golang console. but not working, could you help me to solve? I try so many ways but not worked.

and I also try to remove `dockerClient.ContainerLogs` block, replace with

```
conn, err :=dockerClient.ContainerAttach(ctx,container.ID,types.ContainerAttachOptions{
    Stdout:true,
    Stderr:true,
    Stdin:true,
    Stream:true,
    Logs:true,
})

go io.Copy(os.Stdout,conn.Reader)
```

but still cannot get logs from container. When I run above code, my console is empty, expected result is have "hello" in my console.

Comment: If you run the thing you're trying to run as the main process in the `ContainerCreate` call, its stdout and stderr will come back in the `ContainerLogs` call.  This is the CLI equivalent of just running the command in `docker run`.  You don't need a separate `ContainerExecStart` (`docker exec`) here.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am very excited that someone can answer my question. I tried some methods based on your suggestion, but I can't get the result. Maybe I understand it wrong. could you explain more clearly? Thanks!

Comment: Delete the two `ContainerExec...` calls.  Change the `Cmd:` in the `ContainerCreate` call to have the `{"echo", "hello"}` or the thing you're actually trying to run.

Comment: @DavidMaze I understand you said now, but I want to exec two different cmds in same running container, for example, first run `go build main.go`, and then run "go run main.exe", so I want to create another exec to run another cmd. could you give me some ideas? I try so many methods..

Comment: A shell script; run the "build" step [in a Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/); write some sort of networked controller that runs inside the worker container and accepts abstract commands like "build it"; don't use Docker at all for this kind of workflow.

Comment: @DavidMaze ok, I will try to do, Another alternative is: After create container use sdk, I directly use golang like `cmd := exec.Command("docker","exec")` to invoke `docker exec`, I explain why I do that, I want to implement online compiler,  someone say docker container is good for that. After recv codes from web browser, I **compile** and **run** in container, get stdout, stderr , send back to front-end, that's all. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of *ContainerExecStart* replace it with *ContainerExecAttach*

```
attach, err := dockerClient.ContainerExecAttach(ctx, idResponse.ID, config)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer attach.Close()
go io.Copy(os.Stdout, attach.Reader)
```